# How can I get correct sub-pixel rendering in Java applications?

Tags: arch-linux, java, fonts

I used to use infinality for good-looking fonts, but it hasn't been updated for ages, and it's [now](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=221649) [broken](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=221644). I've since reverted to vanilla freetype and vanilla fonts. I followed [instructions](https://gist.github.com/cryzed/e002e7057435f02cc7894b9e748c5671) to get fonts looking reasonable, specifically, creating `/etc/fonts/local.conf` as per [here](https://gist.github.com/cryzed/e002e7057435f02cc7894b9e748c5671#gistcomment-1966336). I also appended the following line to `/etc/profile.d/jre.sh`

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true'
```

Some of my java apps are fine, but some (e.g. Jabref) look terrible. It looks like the subpixel rendering if totally off. (Previously, with infinality, they looked excellent.)

[image: Jabref]

As per the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Java_Runtime_Environment_fonts), I tried a few different options, such as setting `-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings` to lcd, gasp and off. However, none of these helped. I also tried using different version of java (java-7-openjdk, java-8-jre/jre and java-8-openjdk), but this didn't help either.

Finally, I tried to install jre{7,8}-openjdk-infinality, but they appear to require "infinality support in FreeType", which is obviously now missing. Can I fix this poor rendering in Jabref?

(Originally asked [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=221753), with no response.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ends up that it was just a [bug](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/52625) in the Jabref launcher, and my selected java wasn't being used.

Answer (score 1):

You need a version of openjdk which is built with the freetype support, such as tuxjdk (don't know if it is still supported) or jetbrains' openjdk (available in AUR). And I think it is possible to use the infinality openjdk, with broken dependencies, because its only difference from the original is freetype support (I may be wrong on this).

Comment: Thanks. `tuxjdk` wouldn't build for me, but I *could* install `intellij-jdk`. I selected it with `archlinux-java`, but unfortunately it made no difference. I also tried installing `jdk8-openjdk-infinality`, and it actually worked this time. It both installed and [fixed](http://i.imgur.com/hkxt7Rq.png) this issue. I'll +1 but not accept this answer, because I'd really like a non-Infinality solution, since it's probably only a temporary fix. Cheers.

Comment: May be there are differences between openjdk bundled with a jetbrains IDE and that in AUR, because the bundled one works for me just fine. I don't use any other standalone java apps, so I didn't try the one in AUR, just assumed they are identical.